# How to find all child records for a give parent record in plsql?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, procedure

I have the record structure as below:

> A-->B-->D-->F-->G
>
> A-->C-->U-->W
>
> B-->X-->Y

the relationship of a record can be associated with only one record and no further i.e one record can have only one master. in the above structure record 'A' is the master record.
the table stores data as below:

> A-->B
>
> B-->D
>
> D-->F
>
> F-->G
>
> A-->C

So on....

if I provide 'A' to a PL/SQL procedure, it should return me all the child records associated to it at all level. I suppose only recursive loop can solve this?
kindly provide me a solution folks..!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are right, recursive loop would be required, and you will have to program it. Please spend some time and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) to get accustomed to site. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thanks @Parsania Hardik for your confirmation on the recursive loop logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using a recursive query:

```
WITH t AS (
              SELECT 'A' AS m, 'B' AS c FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B' AS m, 'D' AS c FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'D' AS m, 'F' AS c FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'F' AS m, 'G' AS c FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A' AS m, 'C' AS c FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'C' AS m, 'U' AS c FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'U' AS m, 'W' AS c FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B' AS m, 'X' AS c FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 'X' AS m, 'Y' AS c FROM dual
)
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(t.m) || sys_connect_by_path(c, ', ') AS list
FROM t
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ROOT(t.m) = 'A'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t t2 WHERE t2.m = t.c)
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR c = m;
```

The above query returns this result:

```
A, B, D, F, G
A, B, X, Y
A, C, U, W
```

Comment: this solution holds good for the above data structure. what if I have multiple child records.? what if i am not aware of the count of child records? don't i require a recursive loop??

Comment: The query is recursive itselg: Oracle does the recursive loop for you and give you the final result. In your example A node has two childs: B and C and the query handles them correctly. Can you build a test case to check for your doubt and test the query?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIND_CHILD_RECORD (IN_MASTER_RECORD IN NUMBER)
IS
    V_CHILD_RECORD_LIST   NUMBER_LIST;   -- create a number type colletion list
BEGIN
   -- get all child record for the given master record
 SELECT CHILD_RECORD
 BULK COLLECT INTO V_CHILD_RECORD_LIST
 FROM RELATED_TABLE
WHERE MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER = IN_MASTER_RECORD; -- logic holds good only if one master record is present for one child.

--       iterate over all child records
FOR IDX IN 1 .. V_CHILD_RECORD_LIST.COUNT
LOOP
  -- create a global temp table to store child records
  INSERT INTO TT_CHILD_RECORDS
       VALUES (V_CHILD_RECORD_LIST (IDX));

  COMMIT;
  --call the same procedure recursively
  FIND_CHILD_RECORD (V_CHILD_RECORD_LIST (IDX));
END LOOP;
END;

--TT_CHILD_RECORDS table will hold all child records for a give master.
```

I have written the above code with recursive loop to find all child records. this works for me. correct me if am wrong.. :)